# How different is a ringed space from a vector bundle

Tags: algebraic-geometry, manifolds, vector-bundles

I'm aware that a vector bundle and a ringed space are different objects. They do seem to be similar however.

A vector bundle assigns a vector space structure to each point a base space, while a ringed space assigns to every open set a ring, module, algebra, etc.

Is it possible to define a ringed space on stalks and would it turn out that the assignment of a (say, ring) at each stalk is continuous in an analogous way to that of a vector bundle?

Could anyone also provide more similarities/differences between ringed spaces and vector bundles?

Comment: Vector bundles are the same as locally free modules of finite rank over $\mathcal{O}_X$

Comment: This is exactly the topic of Chapter 13 (p. 369) of [Ravi Vakil's book](http://math.stanford.edu/~vakil/216blog/FOAGnov1817public.pdf).